# Why Javascript function coming undefiend after compiling from webpack?

Tags: javascript, module, scope, webpack

Hi i have used webpack to load my different modules into one bundle.js file , different function from this files are coming undefined in html but if call the same in my entry file ther working or making winndow.fnName .

here is my code 
Test.js

```
var test=function(msg){
console.log(msg)}
module.exports=test;
```

lib.js

```
var lib=function(msg){console.log(msg)}
module.exports=lib;
```

Entire JS

```
var lib=require('./lib.js');
var test=require('./test.js');
```

index.html

```
 test("test called");
 lib("lib also called");
```

Comment: * if i call the same in my entry.js file they are working or asgin the function to winndow.fnName .

Comment: be consist and decide is it `Test.js` or `test.js`

Answer (score 0):

In output file created by webpack your code for Entire JS will look something like this:

```
/*****/
/* 0 */
/*****/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

        'use strict';

        var lib = __webpack_require__(1); // require('./lib.js')
        var test = __webpack_require__(2); // require('./test.js'); 


/*****/ },
```

And since your variables `lib` and `test` are defined in function they aren't assign to window object.

You can workaround to export your `lib` and `test` to window object (I made this assumption based on that you want to use this variables in html file), by doing this:

```
var lib = require('./lib.js');
var test = require('./test.js'); 

window.lib = lib;
window.test = test;
```

Comment: using window.lib isn't it a bad practice exposing my implementation ?

Comment: using js function in html file is bad practice - I only make your code working, not perfect.

Comment: thank you , any idea how do i make my implementation abstract ?

Comment: If you must use function in pure HTML you don't have any other option than assign it to window object. Maybe you didn't know that if you create `var test = function () {};` in global js file your `test` variable will be automatically assign to `window.test`.